# Opening .html.erb files in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, erb

Is there a way to open .html.erb files by themselves in the browser.  The Rails app I am trying to have a look at is in rails 2.3 and will not run locally on the rails server nor will it run when I give the command script/server.

I would just like to open the individual views in the browser by themselves...is this possible?

Comment: No it's not. Can you just open them in your favorite text editor?

Answer (score 1):

In rails4 you can do it like this:

```
erb a.html.erb > a.html
```

Maybe it doesn't work in rails 2.3. If you want to render that view, maybe you can use an action just like `users#index` and change the code to render it:

```
render "devise/mailer/a.html.erb", :layout => false
```

Comment: Where do you put the line, `erb a.html.erb > a.html`?

Answer (score 1):

You can open them in the browser, but the `<% %>` and `<%= %>` tags will get shown as-is instead of executing the Ruby code. These are template files that need to get processed by Rails to fill in data at runtime. Your best bet is TsaiKoga's answer, making a controller action render the template in question.