# ERb file displaying as HTML file in the browser

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm getting back into rails after a hiatus, and ERB is not rendering as expected.  I opened a view from a brand-new project, and one from an old project in both chrome and firefox.  Same problem in all four permutations.

Here's _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@cat) do |f| %>
  <% if @cat.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@cat.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cat from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @cat.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :birth_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :birth_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :color %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :color %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sex %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :sex %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Cat</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', cats_path %>
```

And here's what the browser renders:

[image: contents of html.erb file, displayed as an html file]

I'm running rails 4.2.1 and ruby 2.2.1, and I'm brand new to both versions.

Comment: There's not enough info to help; the relevant project structure (e.g., `app` dir), a sample controller, etc. and maybe a Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a link to the app on github; I'll make sure this SO post reflects whatever the problem and solution end up being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was opening the ERb files in the browser in the manner I'd grown accustomed to doing for HTML files (Command + O -> choose file).  No wonder it was being read as HTML!

For posterity: you must navigate to your app directory in the terminal, start a rails server with "rails s", and navigate to your views from localhost:3000.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a lingering `new.html` in your `views` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I double-checked and it's not so.  Additionally, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292752/opening-html-erb-files-in-browser) implies that rails 4 doesn't allow you to open views in the browser for inspection (and that's as far as I've gotten).

Comment: Can you post your code to a github repo so I could review it?